# How do I make a YouTube RSS Feed in a layout?

Tags: android, rss

LAST EDIT:

I HAVE CREATED AN XML FILE ON A CLOUD SERVICE WITH MY YOUTUBE VIDEOS, AND WITHOUT HAVING TO PARSE THE JSON OF YOUTUBE AN BLA BLA BLA.. :D! THANK YOU ALL, SO I AM THANKED FOR THIS STACKOVERFLOW COMUNITY.

(AND SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH, I SPEAK SPANISH)

I want to do a ListView from an RSS feed (RSS: URL).

And I have tried with a lot of tutorials or examples, but no, I still without understand.

OK, what I want to do is a ListView of a "YouTube Channel's Uploaded Videos", and I want it to have the image, title, description of the video and a link (for they click an go to the video). A refresh button will be fine, and a DB to save cached images and text for offline view.

I am new in this, and I want to learn more, but I am slow, and I did not understood any tutorial what I have viewed.

I expect that at least you will explain me if you understand, and if you already have an RSS reader in a list view, send me it to learn how you did it or something.

I will update this if I have something that you can say me that I am wrong.

(---------- Edited: 18/11/2014 ----------)

I've edited this in other post, but it was closed by show low information.. So.. i'll repost it if you can answer me.. (I am still searching for an answer, but I am lost)..

(---------- Edited: 22/11/2014 ----------)

Recently, I have found a "like" solution, but searching in the same solution in the tutorial, said that it have to be a Web Tree (XML), but, YouTube give it as.. I don't know.. Items that can not be readed by a normal RSS.

Here you are the codes..

### THE MAIN ACTIVITY CLASS

```js
package com.tibi4.alonnso;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.tibi4.alonnso.RssItem;
import com.tibi4.alonnso.ListListener;
import com.tibi4.alonnso.RssReader;

/**
 * Main application activity.
 *
 * Update: Downloading RSS data in an async task
 *
 * @author ITCuties
 *
 */
public class Videos extends Activity {

    // A reference to the local object
    private Videos local;

    /**
     * This method creates main application view
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set view
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_videos);

        // Set reference to this activity
        local = this;

        GetRSSDataTask task = new GetRSSDataTask();

        // Start download RSS task
        task.execute("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/alonsonico10/uploads/?alt=json");

        // Debug the thread name
        Log.d("ITCRssReader", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    private class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssItem> > {
        @Override
        protected List<RssItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // Debug the task thread name
            Log.d("ITCRssReader", Thread.currentThread().getName());

            try {
                // Create RSS reader
                RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(urls[0]);

                // Parse RSS, get items
                return rssReader.getItems();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ITCRssReader", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result) {

            // Get a ListView from main view
            ListView itcItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

            // Create a list adapter
            ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(local,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
            // Set list adapter for the ListView
            itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Set list view item click listener
            itcItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));
        }
    }
}
```

### THE RSSITEM TO SHOW

```js
package com.tibi4.alonnso;

public class RssItem {
    // item title
    private String title;
    // item link
    private String link;
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

### THE LISTLISTENER LISTENER

```js
package com.tibi4.alonnso;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import com.tibi4.alonnso.RssItem;
/**
 * Class implements a list listener.
 * @author ITCuties
 */
public class ListListener implements OnItemClickListener {
    // Our listener will contain a reference to the list of RSS Items
    // List item's reference
    List<RssItem> listItems;
    // And a reference to a calling activity
    // Calling activity reference
    Activity activity;
    /** We will set those references in our constructor.*/
    public ListListener(List<RssItem> aListItems, Activity anActivity) {
        listItems = aListItems;
        activity  = anActivity;
    }

    /** Start a browser with url from the rss item.*/
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        // We create an Intent which is going to display data
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        // We have to set data for our new Intent
        i.setData(Uri.parse(listItems.get(pos).getLink()));
        // And start activity with our Intent
        activity.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

### THE RSSREADER READER

```js
package com.tibi4.alonnso;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import com.tibi4.alonnso.RssItem;

/**
 * Class reads RSS data.
 * @author ITCuties
 */
public class RssReader {
    // Our class has an attribute which represents RSS Feed URL
    private String rssUrl;
    /**
     * We set this URL with the constructor
     */
    public RssReader(String rssUrl) {
        this.rssUrl = rssUrl;
    }
    /**
     * Get RSS items. This method will be called to get the parsing process result.
     * @return
     */
    public List<RssItem> getItems() throws Exception {
        // At first we need to get an SAX Parser Factory object
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        // Using factory we create a new SAX Parser instance
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        // We need the SAX parser handler object
        RssParserHandler handler = new RssParserHandler();
        // We call the method parsing our RSS Feed
        saxParser.parse(rssUrl, handler);
        // The result of the parsing process is being stored in the handler object
        return handler.getItems();
    }
}
```

### THE RSSPARSERHANDLER PARSER

```js
package com.tibi4.alonnso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import com.tibi4.alonnso.RssItem;

/**
 * Created by Alonnso on 22/11/2014.
 */
public class RssParserHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    // List of items parsed
    private List<RssItem> rssItems;
    // We have a local reference to an object which is constructed while parser is working on an item tag
    // Used to reference item while parsing
    private RssItem currentItem;
    // We have two indicators which are used to differentiate whether a tag title or link is being processed by the parser
    // Parsing title indicator
    private boolean parsingTitle;
    // Parsing link indicator
    private boolean parsingLink;

    public RssParserHandler() {
        rssItems = new ArrayList();
    }
    // We have an access method which returns a list of items that are read from the RSS feed. This method will be called when parsing is done.
    public List<RssItem> getItems() {
        return rssItems;
    }
    // The StartElement method creates an empty RssItem object when an item start tag is being processed. When a title or link tag are being processed appropriate indicators are set to true.
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if ("item".equals(qName)) {
            currentItem = new RssItem();
        } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
            parsingTitle = true;
        } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
            parsingLink = true;
        }
    }
    // The EndElement method adds the  current RssItem to the list when a closing item tag is processed. It sets appropriate indicators to false -  when title and link closing tags are processed
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if ("item".equals(qName)) {
            rssItems.add(currentItem);
            currentItem = null;
        } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
            parsingTitle = false;
        } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
            parsingLink = false;
        }
    }
    // Characters method fills current RssItem object with data when title and link tag content is being processed
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        if (parsingTitle) {
            if (currentItem != null)
                currentItem.setTitle(new String(ch, start, length));
        } else if (parsingLink) {
            if (currentItem != null) {
                currentItem.setLink(new String(ch, start, length));
                parsingLink = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This codes where with other RSS URL, and worked fine, but is the "YOUTUBE" RSS the thing that give me troubles.

(---------- Edited: 22/11/2014 ----------)